# Error while pattern matching io::Result

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
fn main() {
    use std::io::prelude::*;
    use std::fs::File;

    fn write_file() -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut f = try!(File::create("foo.txt"));
        try!(f.write_all(b"Hello, world!"));
    }

    match write_file() {
        Ok => println!("File was written"),
        Err(ex) => println!("{}", ex)
    };
}
```

I have an error:

```
src/main.rs:11:9: 11:11 error: this pattern has 0 fields, but the corresponding variant has 1 field [E0023]
src/main.rs:11         Ok => println!("File was written"),
                       ^~
```

Why and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Ok => println!("File was written"),
```

should be

```
Ok(()) => println!("File was written"),
```

because the `Ok` constructor always takes an argument, even if that argument is `()`. You could also use `Ok(_)` if you prefer.

Comment: Or `Ok(..)`, just in case the standard library decides to change and break every Rust program in existence. Seriously, I tend to use the `..` as it's more universally applicable when I don't want *any* of the values.